# Displaying PDF content within Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, pdf

The requirement is below:

--> The version of Silverlight is 3.0
--> I don’t want to convert it to jpg, png etc. since I want end user to copy data from the displayed data.
--> I am currently using IFrame to display pdf but it has some problems like IFrame not supported consistently across different browsers.

--> I could not find any control (third party) that displays pdf with SL 3.0 Most of the controls that I came across are either for 4.0 or does conversion into some png kind of format which doesn’t allow user to copy data. If there is nothing that can be done from SL easily then I am ready to use 3rd party controls that are meant to work with SL 3.0 and allow end user to copy data.

--> I thought about reading data from pdf and displaying again over some control like text block but this would eventually become complicated for scenarios where I have to maintain formatting and displaying images etc.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gonna lose this one.  I don't know of anything that renders PDF well in Silverlight 4 let alone Silverlight 3.

Whilst this comment "IFrame not supported consistently across different browsers" may be true IFrame is generally supported by the all major browsers.

Hence your best bet is to test and tweak your IFrame solution with these browsers.

Alternatively launch an independent browser window to display the PDF or let the users local system use whatever it has installed to display the PDF.